# Adding a scroll view in android studio

Tags: android, scrollview

Can someone help me explain and paste the correct code into my code to add a scroll view into my Android project?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@drawable/achtergrond_top2000_2"
    tools:context=".Muziek">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Spelen_Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold_italic"
        android:text="Muziek"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:translationY="130dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/NPO_Radio2"
        android:layout_width="87dp"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:scaleY="1"
        android:translationY="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/npo_radio2"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Top2000"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:scaleY="1"
        android:translationY="90dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/top_2000"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/spelen_scrollen"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:translationY="250dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/roller_coaster_lijst_button"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                android:translationX="-10dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/roller_coaster_lijst" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_1"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lijst_divider" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bohemian_rhapsody_lijst_button"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                android:translationX="7dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/bohemian_rhapsody_lijst" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_2"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lijst_divider" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/hotel_california_lijst_button"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                android:translationX="-1dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/hotel_california_lijst" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_3"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lijst_divider" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/piano_man_lijst_button"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                android:translationX="-29dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/piano_man_lijst" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_4"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lijst_divider" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/stairways_to_heaven_lijst_button"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                android:translationX="0dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/stairway_to_heaven_lijst" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_5"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lijst_divider" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/black_lijst_button"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                android:translationX="-45dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/black_lijst" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_6"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lijst_divider" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/avond_lijst_button"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                android:translationX="-3dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/avond_lijst" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_7"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:scaleX="1"
                android:scaleY="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lijst_divider" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure you use tags relevant to your problem, the [tag:android-studio] tag is only for IDE issues.

Comment: Please add a desired result and current problem in your question. Asking like 'Paste correct code' won't give you any answer honestly.

Answer (score 0):

here I have tried your code and changed maybe help you

> 

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Spelen_Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    android:text="Muziek"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:translationY="130dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/NPO_Radio2"
    android:layout_width="87dp"
    android:layout_height="87dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleX="1"
    android:scaleY="1"
    android:translationY="20dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Top2000"
    android:layout_width="133dp"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:scaleX="1"
    android:scaleY="1"
    android:translationY="90dp"

    />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/spelen_scrollen"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/roller_coaster_lijst_button"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:translationX="-10dp"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_1"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bohemian_rhapsody_lijst_button"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:translationX="7dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_2"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/hotel_california_lijst_button"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:translationX="-1dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_3"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/piano_man_lijst_button"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:translationX="-29dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_4"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/stairways_to_heaven_lijst_button"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:translationX="0dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_5"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/black_lijst_button"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:translationX="-45dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_6"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/avond_lijst_button"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:translationX="-3dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lijst_divider_7"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here What you did wrong was You made your scroll view to  `android:translationY="250dp"`

Just Copy and past my XML file to your will do your inside scroll

Comment: Glad to know that if its help you make it accept answer @Thomas